# jQuery remove contents when i try to play a different video on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a page where i need to play youtube video in same page and when user click on any listed videos it should copy title & date to the active video area.

In my case it copies the content & changes the video but it removed the active link when i click on the video list.

Try to click on links, it will remove them one by one & video wont also show

My CODE on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSMZ9/33/)

HTML

```
<div style="float:left; width=800px;" id="video_container">
    <div class="active-iframe">
        <iframe width="438" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vOnCRWUsSGA?wmode=transparent&rel=0&theme=light&color=white&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<span class="active-video-title">Title</span>

<span class="active-video-date">Date</span>

<div class="row">
    <br> <a href="oDAw7vW7H0c" class="play-youtube">
            <span class="youtube-thumbnail">Thumnnail 1</span>
       <div class="title-wrapper">
            <span class="title">Title of the Video 1</span>
             <span class="date">Date  1</span>
        </div>
        </a>

    <br> <a href="5F-Wge37_ys" class="play-youtube">
            <span class="youtube-thumbnail">Thumnnail 2</span>
        <div class="title-wrapper">
            <span class="title">Title of the Video 2</span>
             <span class="date">Date  2</span>
            </div>
        </a>

</div>
<div class="row2">
    <br> <a href="oDAw7vW7H0c" class="play-youtube">
            <span class="youtube-thumbnail">featured Thumnnail 1</span>
        <div class="title-wrapper-control">
            <span class="featured-title">featured Title of the Video 1</span>
             <span class="featured-date">featured Date  1</span>
        </div>
        </a>

    <br> <a href="5F-Wge37_ys" class="play-youtube">
            <span class="youtube-thumbnail">featured Thumnnail 2</span>
        <div class="title-wrapper-control">
            <span class="featured-title">featured Title of the Video 2</span>
             <span class="featured-date">featured Date  2</span>
        </div>
        </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the line

```
$(".active-iframe").html($(this).html(htm));
```

that replaces the HTML of your link, *not* the source of the iframe. Instead :

```
$('iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL);
```

and skip `var htm = ..`

Demo / forked fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5RnAe/

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```js
$(".active-iframe").html($(this).html(htm));
```

to

```js
$(".active-iframe").html(htm);
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/KSMZ9/40/